# How to update my git working copy to a previous revision

Tags: git

Is there a nice way to change my Git working copy to something a given number of commits ago.

E.g. To see 3 commits into the past, something like:

```
git reset HEAD - 3
```

The use case here is that I just want to see if the tests that are failing in the current working copy were also failing before my latest commit. I don't necessarily want to make any changes to the previous versions. I would then want to change the working copy back to the latest commit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you simply want to *look* at a previous commit (without altering the state of your branch/repository), use `git checkout`.

```
git checkout HEAD~3
```

If you decide you want to do development off of this point, you can then branch.

```
git checkout -b specialFeature47
```

To return to the present, simply checkout the branch name you were on.

```
git checkout master
```

Be weary of the suggested `git reset` solutions. Those actually move your branch pointer (effectively deleting those 3 commits).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's possible:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~3
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I forgot to mention in my original question that I also want to be able to move forward again. Basically, I just want to roll back and forward easily. What is the command for that?

Comment: @KevinStembridge: There is no equivalent syntax for rolling forward. You need to determine that commit by other means. For example, if the HEAD before the rollback is the HEAD of a branch, you can simply use `git reset --hard <branch>`. Otherwise you might want to tag the current head before rolling back. Finally, `git reflog` shows changes to HEAD, so you could extract the hash of the previous HEAD from this.

Comment: see [`man gitrevisisons`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), `@{n}` and `@{-n}` are very helpful.

Comment: You could also do an interactive rebase with `git rebase -i HEAD~3` (useful if you want to make changes to an old revision) or create a backup branch that you can use to return to the old head later `git branch temp_backup`

Answer (score 2):

You can always do:

git checkout HEAD~15

and move 15 commits back. The current tip is completely undisturbed, you can move around, even build that version and check, etc. To go back, just do a `git checkout mybranch`. If you want to start working there (and leave the original branch on ice) you can `git branch newbranch`, and work with `newbranch` from now on.

Consider carefully what you are doing before using any history-rewriting command (`commit --amend`, `rebase`, `reset` and such), there is real potential of *massive* loss of work there. Branching in `git` is dirt cheap, most of what you can accomplish by rewinding history can be done by just creating a new branch starting somewhere in the past, and perhaps switching it with the current `master` branch. The work done on the old branch might come in handy later; and if it doesn't, the cost of keeping it around is probably negligible anyway.